# How to add additional tag to a specific word using regular expression and php

Tags: php, regex

I want to add   into #indlude. i.e if

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h>
int main()
```

is my target string then it will be :

```
  <span class="header">#include<stdio.h></span>
  <span class="header">#include<math.h></span>
  int main()
```

I tried using regular expression as follows:

```
<?php 
$input = '#include<stdio.h> int main()';
$input = preg_replace('/(#(\w)+<(\w)+.h>)/','<span class="header">$1</span>',$input);

echo $input;
?>
```

But no luck. Any idea?

Comment: `w` is not `\w`, `w+` matches `wwww`. You probably meant to use `'/^#include<[^>]+>$/m'` and replace with `'<span class="header">$0</span>'`

Comment: Note that you should html encode '<' and '>'  around <stdio.h>

Comment: Also, in your current regex `.` matches any character. You need to use `\.` to match a `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you state otherwise, you don't need any capture groups or start of line anchors; just replace the fullstring match (`$0`)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BaY1d))

```
$string = <<<STRING
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
STRING;

echo preg_replace('~#include<[^>]+>~', '<span class="header">$0</span>', $string);
```

Output:

```
<span class="header">#include<math.h></span>
<span class="header">#include<stdio.h></span>

int main()
```

The negated character class (`[^>]`) will greedily match all characters between `<` and `>` -- this is preferable as a matter of pattern efficiency.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that `$0` matches the whole string. Have an upvote :)