# match multiple line using regular expression and modify these matched lines using regexp and PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to match multiple lines based on regular expression. Suppose I have the following string:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
```

I want to replace `#include<math.h>` with `<span class="header">#include<math.h> </span>` and `#include<stdio.h>` with `<span class="header">#include<stdio.h></span>`. The final filtered string will looks like:

```
<span class="header">#include<math.h></span>
<span class="header">#include<stdio.h></span>

int main()
```

At first I am trying to match my target word to reformat as follows:
/#include<[^>]+>/m
But this only select first line and the following is working for multiple lines:
/#include<[^>]+>/gm

Now I am trying to prepare these matched lines as follows:

```
 <span class="header">#include<math.h></span>
 <span class="header">#include<stdio.h></span>
```

**code:**

```
  <?php 
    $input = '#include<math.h>
        #include<stdio.h> 
       int main()';
    $input = preg_replace('/(#include<[^>]+>)/gm','<span class="header">$0</span>',$input);

    echo $input;
    ?>
```

This codes gives an error and came to know 'g' is not supported by php. This simple task kills my day. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) or [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead of making it multiline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add additional tag to a specific word using regular expression and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470113/how-to-add-additional-tag-to-a-specific-word-using-regular-expression-and-php). This question seems incredibly similar to your previous question, please explain how this one's different, and why you feel justified in asking a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PHP solution to your problem:

```
$str = <<<EOF
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
EOF;
$str = preg_replace('/(#include<[^>]+>)/', '<span class="header">$1</span>', $str);
echo $str;
```

This outputs:

```
<span class="header">#include<math.h></span>
<span class="header">#include<stdio.h></span>

int main()
```

[3v41.org demo](https://3v4l.org/TJUOu)

`preg_replace` will match *all* occurrences, instead of just the first. However, if you only want to *match* occurences, instead of replace them, you'll need to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`, because PHP doesn't support the `/g` flag and instead has the `preg_match_all` function for this.

---

For RegExr, you need to add the global `g` flag to capture multiple matches, instead of just the first.

Your final regex should look like this:

```
/#include<[^>]+>/gm
```

[image: RegExr screenshot]

[RegExr demo](https://regexr.com/43odi)

Comment: @David. Thanks for your time. How to make this two lines as: <span class="header">#include<math.h></span>
<span class="header">#include<stdio.h></span> in php?

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan You should probably update your question with specific details about the _PHP solution_ you've tried, and why it's not working, because right now your question is about your regex not working in RegExr.

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan Please see updated answer, you shouldn't put the `/g` flag in the PHP `preg_replace` function. Also, PHP capture groups start from `$1`, not `$0`.